# Problem in reflecting the records created through trigger in AssociationAttribute, Linq

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, linq-to-sql

There is one-to-n relationship (foreign-key relationship) between tables As and Bs. Every time a new record is added in As, a trigger "after update" in table As creates n records in table Bs.

There are two Linq-to-SQL classes A and B representing the tables As and Bs respectively.

The class A contains Bs property an EntitySet(of B). Similarly in class B, there is a property A, an EntityRef(of A)

Look into following code:

```
 Public Function NewRecsOfB() As Integer
    Dim objDCDC As New DataClassesDataContext(gstrDatabaseValues)
    'gstrdatabaseValues contains the connection string

    Dim objA As New A


    objDCDC.As.InsertOnSubmit(objA)
    objDCDC.SubmitChanges()
    NewRecsOfB = objA.Bs.count
    objDCDC.Connection.Close()
    objDCDC = Nothing
End Function
```

When above function is executed the result is always 0. Whereas there are six records new records has been added to table Bs every time the above function is executed.

Please help in resolving the above problem. Thanks.

Comment: * Whereas six new records get added to table Bs every time the function NewRecsOfB is executed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the best way, but you can `Dispose()` of your data context, create new one, get new copy of `objA` by id and retrieve `Bs` from that.

Comment: If I add an record in table As and I try to access the new records in table Bs after few seconds it get reflected but not immediately.

Comment: if know any expert on this field pls. refer this problem to them. it will be a great help to me.

Comment: my mistake, your suggestion has worked. Thank you. Actually I was referring the earlier object of A. Even after executing dispose function of datacontext.